# Number of occurrences of a method NDepend

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ndepend, cqlinq

I need to write an NDepend rule that checks if every await of an Async Method uses ConfigureAwait(false).

I check if a method uses ConfigureAwait(Boolean). If that method doesn't use it, it has violated the rule.

```
from m in JustMyCode.Methods 
where
!(m.IsUsingMethod("System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ConfigureAwait(Boolean)") ||
m.IsUsingMethod("System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.ConfigureAwait(Boolean)")) && 
m.IsAsync

select new { 
 m,
 m.MethodsCalled
}
```

This code works fine if you are sure that every async method uses one await.
But what if a method uses two awaits? then you could count all occurrences of await in that method.

**Example**

```
public async Task Foo()
{
  await DoSomething();
}

public async Task Bar()
{
  await DoSomething().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task Stone()
{
  await DoSomething();
  await DoSomething().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Foo and Stone Has violated the rule.

With my code I can see that Foo has violated the rule, but Stone hasn't violated It.

With 'MethodsCalled' I am able to check if a method uses ConfigureAwait(), which is nice. But again I am not able to check how many occurrences of await and ConfigureAwait() 'Stone' has.

Comment: > But again I am not able to check how many occurrences of await and ConfigureAwait() 'Stone' has.   --   This feature is not support yet by the code querying, so for now you can only detect that Foo() is wrong, but not Stone() wrongness.